# Passing Parameters from shortcode to enqueue script

Tags: plugins

I need to pass the parameters present in the second script to the first script in the wp_enqueue_script

```
/*FIRST SCRIPT*/
function add_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('kross-js', 'https://'EDITOR-ID'kross1.com/widget/6.js?lang=it&be_id='USER-ID', array(), '' , false);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_script' );

/*SECOND SCRIPT*/

function kross_shortcode( $atts ) {

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'USER-ID' => '',
            'EDITOR-ID' => '',
        ),
        $atts
    );

return '<div id="kross-widget">  </div> ';

}

add_shortcode( 'kross', 'kross_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can enqueue scripts (and styles) in the shortcode like that :

```
add_shortcode("kross", function ($atts, $content, $tag) {


    $atts = shortcode_atts([
        'user-id' => '',
        'editor-id' => '',
    ], $atts);



    wp_enqueue_script(
          "kross-js"
        , "https://{$atts["editor-id"]}kross1.com/widget/6.js?lang=it&be_id={$atts["user-id"]}"
    );


    $result = "kross result";

    return $result;

});
```